# Versioning geodatabases

Tags: c#, enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to reconcile and post the edits. I would like to know if I can post the versions to two different parents. Could some one help me with c# coding on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly rec&post directly to both parents.

In ArcMap, you get this error:
[image]

But you can rec&post to a common ancestor version (grandparent, great-grandparent, etc), and then reconcile down the branch of the second parent that you want to post to.

You can rec&post with the IVersionEdit interfaces in ArcObjects
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m0v000000

```
bool reconcileresult = version.Reconcile4(
                parentVersionName, // targetVersion
                true, //acquire lock
                true, // abort if conflict 
                false,  //child doesn't win
                columnLevelConflict); //use column-level conflicts

            if (!reconcileresult)
            {
                version.Post(ArcMap.Editor.EditWorkspace.GetParentVersionName());
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't post two parent version if they're in 2 different state tree.
Let me example this, let's say there is a Default version and child under Default, and grandchildren under children... 
So the littlest child can post all edits to child then child will reconcile/post to Default.

But what if there would be another tree? Just like them. So the child under 2. tree can't reconcile/post to another child/parent which are under 1. tree.

I hope I understood correctly your question.